# how can I save/restrore ListView's state when stacking from bottom?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView and 2 situations:

```
setStackFromBottom(false)
```

1) When I arrive at the bottom, I use `Parceable currentScrollState = lv.onSaveInstanceState();` to save the state of the `ListView`. Then some more data is loaded, Adapter's data set changes and I use `lv.onRestoreInstanceState(currentScrollState);` to keep the scroll state equal to its previous state. This works fine.

2) However, when I use `setStackFromBottom(true)` this doesn't work and the `ListView` always scrolls to its bottom edge after the Adapter's data set changes.

I tried to log its state and found out that it is saved correctly for the 1st case:

```
   AbsListView.SavedState{4260fed0 selectedId=-9223372036854775808 firstId=10 viewTop=-112 position=10 height=1497 filter=null checkState=null}
   AbsListView.SavedState{4263cad8 selectedId=-9223372036854775808 firstId=30 viewTop=-114 position=30 height=1497 filter=null checkState=null}
   AbsListView.SavedState{428ba9e0 selectedId=-9223372036854775808 firstId=50 viewTop=-102 position=50 height=1497 filter=null checkState=null}
```

When using `setStackFromBottom(true)` the `ListView` is unable to save the state correctly:

```
  AbsListView.SavedState{4262c808 selectedId=-9223372036854775808 firstId=-1 viewTop=0 position=0 height=1497 filter=null checkState=null}
  AbsListView.SavedState{428ac3b8 selectedId=-9223372036854775808 firstId=-1 viewTop=0 position=0 height=1497 filter=null checkState=null}
```

**The question:** how can I save/restore `ListView`'s scroll state when using `setStackFromBottom(true)` ?

Comment: Why do you want to use setStackFromBottom() ?

Comment: Try ListView:getFirstVisiblePosition() and restore with ListView:setSelection()

Comment: @greenapps thanks, this worked for me, please post it as answer. Why do I need to use it? Because there are situations where a bottom-to-top approach is reasonable, for example a chat where you want the last item (latest message) to appear at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ListView:getFirstVisiblePosition()` and restore with `ListView:setSelection()`.